# How to achieve thread blocking in CAPL

Tags: capl

Now i am facing a problem with CAPL:

1. I have a CAN message with 10ms's cycle
2. When i receive this message i have an action which may cost more than 20ms to be done

So is there any method to block the "on message xxx" thread in CAPL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to disable that thread. 
I would recommend to condition your processing to an if in your on message xxx {}.

```
on message 10msMessage
{
  if (20msTask_Free) 
   {
    20msTask_Free=0;
    20msTask();
   }
}
```

Also, you have to set 20msTaks_Free=1 somewhere, when you feel safe to process it again (dunno, at the end of 20msTask()).

Of course, my solutions caveat is that you cannot execute on every 10msMessage the 20msTask. But that is self explanatory, and I gorked from your description that you don't need all the time this thread.

Comment: Thank you! I've already modified my code like this. And to know that the CAPL can not block the thread is also very useful to me :)

Comment: Please mark this Answer as "Accept this answer" to make sure that it is updated correctly.